# Exec to launch php as background process

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am struggling with getting a php file to run in the background with PHP's exec(). As a first test, I tried :

```
exec("ls -l > logfile.txt 2> errfile.txt &");
```

That works fine. logfile.txt gets filled with a directory listing.

Per instructions in the php documentation, since the exec kicks off a process that runs in the background, standard out (and standard error) are redirected to a file.

Now, I try

```
exec("/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/my.php > logfile.txt 2> errorfile.txt &");
```

It appears nothing happens.

Here are test files that I'm trying:

alpha.php

```
<?php 
    $version="a"; 
    // Go do something we do not need to wait for. 
    exec("/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/beta.php > logfile.txt 2> errorfile.txt &"); 
?>

<html> 
    <head><title>Test</title></head> 
    <body> 
    <p>This is Alpha version <?php echo $version; ?></p> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

beta.php

```
<?php 
    if (!($fp = fopen('/home/johnst12/public_html/workshops/admin/betadata.txt', 'w'))) { exit;} 
    fprintf($fp, "Proof that Beta executed."); 
    fclose($fp); 
?>
```

If I run beta.php directly, it works fine. Betadata.txt gets the message.

If I run alpha.php to launch beta.php, betadata.txt is not created. logfile.txt and errorfile.txt remain empty (expected).

I am sure that the path to php, and the path to my php file are correct.

Googling for clarification has not been fruitful. A couple of common themes seem to be (a) running out of resources? (b) lack of permission on the target php file? Out of resources seems unlikely. The permission on the script is global read 644 (rw-r--r--). I tried adding execute (755) just in case it would help. It made no difference.

PHP version 5.3.21
Linux/Apache system. 
safe_mode Off

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: The user have permission to write in the folder with this user.
Try to run a whoami and in the server su - "theuser" and touch a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all : Have you verified that /usr/bin/php is the correct path to PHP?

Php doesn't like running like that. Something to do with stdin. Try with nohup:

```
exec("nohup /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/beta.php > logfile.txt 2> errorfile.txt &");
```

With -f anything else that looks like a flag will go to PHP, so if you wanted to pass a "-x" option to your script then you'd have to

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/beta.php -- -x
```

Without, options before the filename go to PHP and after go to the script.

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/beta.php -x
```

I assume you've already looked at the two files in case they have output or errors?

**A few other things to check:**

Delete the two files. Are they recreated each time this code runs?

```
exec("nohup /usr/bin/php -v > logfile.txt &");
```

should output version information to that log file.

```
exec("/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/beta.php > logfile.txt 2> errorfile.txt");
```

should run the script properly (but not in the background).